# Parse save pointer

Tags: ios, swift, parse-platform

This is my code that tries to save the table/Class inscricoes

```
    view.showHUD(view)
    var inscricaoClass = PFObject(className: INSCRICAO_CLASS_NAME)
    inscricaoClass[INSCRICAO_SORTEIO_ID] = self.eventObj.objectId
    inscricaoClass.saveInBackgroundWithBlock { (success, error) -> Void in
        if error == nil {
            self.view.hideHUD()                
        } else {  errorAlert.show();  self.view.hideHUD()  }
    }
```

**This is my class / table where sorteioId is a pointer to my table/class sorteios**
[image]

**when I try to save an error of warning that can not save as a string pointer.**

[Error]: invalid type for key sorteioId, expected *Sorteios, but got string (Code: 111, Version: 1.7.5)*

**How do I send a pointer to table / class using parse?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You first need an instance of PFObject of type Sorteios. Revise your code like so:

```
view.showHUD(view)
var query = PFQuery(className: "Sorteios")
query.getObjectInBackgroundWithId(self.eventObj.objectId) {
   (object: PFObject?, error: NSError?) -> Void in
      if error == nil && object != nil {
          // after finding Sorteios, you can assign it to inscricaoClass
          var inscricaoClass = PFObject(className: INSCRICAO_CLASS_NAME)
          inscricaoClass[INSCRICAO_SORTEIO_ID] = object

          inscricaoClass.saveInBackgroundWithBlock { (success, error) -> Void in
              if error == nil {
                  self.view.hideHUD()                
             } else {
                 errorAlert.show();  self.view.hideHUD()  }
             }
      }
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much, helped me a lot !!It worked perfectly